# INSERT INTO ... in MariaDB in Ubuntu under Windows WSL2 results in corrupted data in some columns

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, wsl-2

I am migrating a MariaDB database into a Linux docker container.

I am using mariadb:latest in Ubuntu 20 LTS via Windows 10 WSL2 via VSCode Remote WSL.

I have copied the `sql` dump into the container and imported it into the InnoDB database which has DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8. It does not report any errors:

```
> source /test.sql
```

That file does this (actual data truncated for this post):

```
  USE `mydb`;
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `opsitemtest`;

  CREATE TABLE `opsitemtest` (
    `opId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `opKey` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `opName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `opDetails` longtext,
    PRIMARY KEY (`opId`),
    KEY `token` (`opKey`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4784 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  insert  into `opsitemtest`(`opId`,`opKey`,`opName`,`opDetails`) values
  (4773,'8vlte0755dj','VTools addin for MSAccess','<p>There is a super helpful ...'),
  (4774,'8vttlcr2fTA','BAS OLD QB','<ol>\n<li><a href=\"https://www.anz.com/inetbank/bankmain.asp\" ...'),
  (4783,'9c7id5rmxGK','STP - Single Touch Payrol','<h1>Gather data</h1>\n<ol style=\"list-style-type: decimal;\"> ...');
```

If I `source` a subset of 12 records of the table in question all the columns are correctly populated.

If I `source` the **full set** of data for the same table ( 4700 rows ) where everything else is the same, many of the opDetails long text fields have a length showing in sqlYog but no data is visible. If I run a SELECT on that column there are no errors but some of the opDetails fields are "empty" (meaning: you can't see any data), and when I serialize that field, the opDetails column of some records (not all) has

```
"opDetails" : "\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\",
```

( and many more \u0000 ).

The opDetails field contains HTML fragments. I am guessing it is something to do with that content and possibly the CHARSET, although that doesn't explain why the error shows up only when there are a large number of rows imported. The same row imported via a set of 12 rows works correctly.

The same test of the full set of data on a Windows box with MariaDB running on that host (ie no Ubuntu or WSL etc) all works perfectly.

I tried setting the table charset to utf8 to match the database default but that had no effect. I assume it is some kind of Windows WSL issue but I am running the `source` command on the container all *within* the Ubuntu host.

The MariaDB data folder is mapped using a volume, again all inside the Ubuntu container:

```
volumes:
      - ../flowt-docker-volumes/mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions while I go through and try manually removing content until it works? I am really in the dark here.

**EDIT:** I just ran the same import process on a Mac to a MariaDB container on the OSX host to check whether it *was* actually related to Windows WSL etc and the OSX database has the same issue. So maybe it is a MariaDB docker issue?

**EDIT 2:** It looks like it has nothing to do with the actual content of opDetails. For a given row that is showing the symptoms, whether or not the data gets imported correctly seems to depend on how many rows I am importing! For a small number of rows, all is well. For a large number there is missing data, but always the same rows and opDetails field. I will try importing in small chunks but overall the table isn't THAT big!

**EDIT 3:** I tried a docker-compose without a volume and imported the data directly into the MariaDB container. Same problem. I was wondering whether it was a file system incompatibility or some kind of speed issue. Yes, grasping at straws!

Thanks,
Murray

Comment: You create a table opsitemtest but insert your data into opsitemtest2 ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter: Thanks for noticing. ;-) That was a typo in the creation of this post to reduce the data size. Doh! It isn't the problem though because my actual code uses the same table for both create and insert.

Comment: \u0000 is the unicode expression for the NULL control character. Since it is a non-printable character with some special meaning it not show depending on the settings of your editor or tool. From the description I'd guess the characters actually are in the SQL file and the text editor might not show them. For columns only containing NULL characters the simplest thing probably would be something like `update opsitemtest set opDetails = trim(BOTH '\u0000' FROM opDetails)`

Comment: Thanks @RolandKreuzer. I tried that. No errors, "No rows affected" and still the issue.  I just added an update above.

Comment: If your error log looks like [MDEV-29015](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29015), [MDEV-28580](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-28580), or [MDEV-24189](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-24189), then it is the [wsl 8443](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8443) issue that I'm waiting on getting fixed. In the mean time I've got a container `quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-devel:10.3-mdev-29015-avoid-wsl8443` waiting for someone, hopefully you, to test that works around the WSL issue.

Comment: Thanks @danblack. No, I am not getting any errors at all - just corrupted data.

Comment: There's no `show warnings` after the `source /test.sql`? You can test the very latest 10.8 development branch, `quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-devel:10.8` as this will be what the next mariadb:latest will behave like after the next release. I'm out of ideas. A new [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org), with source data [via ftp if willing](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/meta/mariadb-ftp-server/). If you do have time to test MDEV-29015 that would be appreciated too. There's still time to get a fix in to work around the known WSL issue before the next release.

Comment: @danblack. No warnings nor errors. Just a list of things like: Query OK, 4386 rows affected (0.104 sec) Records: 4386  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0. In the morning I will try using MySql instead. Thinking if that also fails it is probably MY error somewhere. If it works, maybe is a MariaDB problem and I will do what you suggest re bug etc.

Comment: `mariadb:10.7` (or earlier) is also a test point. The latest on 10.8 also has a jammy base image (previous has focal) that has exposed a few issues in host compatibility under limited circumstances.

Comment: As per Edit 1 above I am also thinking it is unlikely to be a WSL issue since I have the same issue with the same image on my OSX machine. I will try previous versions too. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

OK. I got it working. :-)

One piece of info I neglected to mention, and it might not be relevant anyway, is that I was importing from an sql dump from `10.1.48-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1` because I was migrating a legacy app.

So, with my docker-compose:

| Version | Result |
| --- | --- |
| mysql:latest | data imported correctly |
| mariadb:latest | failed as per this issue |
| mariadb:mariadb:10.7.4 | failed as per this issue |
| mariadb:mariadb:10.7 | failed as per this issue |
| mariadb:10.6 | data imported correctly |
| mariadb:10.5 | data imported correctly |
| mariadb:10.2 | data imported correctly |

Important: remember to completely remove the external volume mount folder content between tests!

So, now I am not sure whether the issue was some kind of sql incompatibility that I need to be aware of, or whether it is a bug that was introduced between v10.6 and 10.7. Therefore I have not logged a bug report. If others with more expertise think this is a bug, I am happy to make a report.

For now I am happy to use 10.6 so I can progress the migration- the deadline is looming!

So, this is sort of "solved".

Thanks for all your help. If I discover anything further I will post back here.
Murray